# Don’t Leave Us!

Tags: riddle, word

We are beautiful

as we dance with the wind’s feelings.

You will be captured by the sight of us;

but soon, you’ll get tired.

Don’t leave us, don’t leave us!

Are we told cold

for your heart?

Are we too delicate

that you can hold onto us

for only a second?

We will leave you cold

but with happiness.

Bye-bye, bye-bye

to your warmness,

to your hands,

and your melted heart.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> snow/snowflakes

We are beautiful
as we dance with the wind’s feelings.

> Snow falling is a beautiful sight, especially when the wind persuades it to fall one way or another

You will be captured by the sight of us;
but soon, you’ll get tired.

> You can stay watching the snowflakes dance their way to the ground for a while, but it is repetitive (and boring after a while), and staying out in the cold is also tiring

Don’t leave us, don’t leave us!
Are we told cold
for your heart?
Are we too delicate
that you can hold onto us
for only a second?

> This refers to how snowflakes melt rapidly when they come into contact with skin

We will leave you cold

> Snow will indeed leave you cold

but with happiness.

> winter and snow can bring many people happiness

Bye-bye, bye-bye
to your warmness,
to your hands,
and your melted heart.

Comment: Congratulations, you are correct :)